# Remove rounded corners from <select> element

Tags: jquery, css

How can I remove the rounded corners on a select element?

I tried adding the following code but it removed the arrows and cut off the bottom of the placeholder text:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

[see website](http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/editorial/)

Comment: that only works in safari, and google chrome...

Comment: Select elements are styled differently by different browsers. If you want to truly customise your select elements, you'll essentially need to create your own.

Comment: You must search first! http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/ and lots of styles for select are available.

Comment: And you must use all vendor prefixes as well as default style.

Comment: Don't use your own web page to give examples. As soon as your problem is fixed, this question would become useless to anybody else. Try with a `clean code` in a shared and permanent service, *as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example*.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class that's causing problems in your CSS:

```
.dropdown-search .form-control {
   padding-bottom: 8px; /* CHANGE THIS TO 0px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you have added padding bottom to select

```
.dropdown-search .form-control {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

in file http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css?ver=1.0 on line 1349

Replace it with this code

```
.dropdown-search .form-control {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)